# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't see 64gb sd card

Tags: 16.04

I have tried to plug in smaller sd cards like 8gb and it seemed to mount just fine. My 64 gb sd card sometimes does mount if I run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

and

```
sudo depmod
```

then also restart and that only worked a few times. The sd card is in exfat format and works fine in my windows partition. I have tried a lot of stuff that I could find.
Does anyone also have this and how can I fix it?

> 

```
*-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: TOSHIBA MQ02ABF1
       vendor: Toshiba
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 1E
       serial: 26BQCJ0IT
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=ce85788c-fcdb-45fe-97c8-ffcb78c6e4fa logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
maksim@ideapad-15ISK:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 79.5 MiB, 83349504 bytes, 162792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 820.9 MiB, 860745728 bytes, 1681144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CE85788C-FCDB-45FE-97C8-FFCB78C6E4FA

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2      534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      567296  945545215 944977920 450.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   945545216 1691889663 746344448 355.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1691889664 1932922879 241033216   115G MBR partition scheme
/dev/sda6  1932922880 1949347839  16424960   7.9G MBR partition scheme
/dev/sda7  1949425664 1951473663   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8  1951475712 1953523711   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `lshw -class disk` or `sudo fdisk -l` in the terminal, then locate the name of the sd you want to mount.

Then run `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sd? /media/? -o force` replace the '?' with the drive name and mount-point.

The driver mount-point can be anything... For example, you could create a directory /media/external.

(To create the directory, use `sudo mkdir /media/external`)

don't forget to up-vote and accept it if it works

Comment: i added what I got from running both commands

Comment: was the media card plugged in when you did this?

Comment: I did it right after you sent me the reply yes the media card was plugged in

Comment: if it's not showing there, then I think there has been physical damage to your sd card. Consider replacing it but keep it in case someone comes along with a better method to fix it.

Comment: I have work in Ubuntu every once in a while and I also have it worked every time in Windows

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2`
and

`sudo depmod` and then try `sudo fdisk -l` again then post the output

Comment: Still the same thing